# Deleted azure app service still accessible

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I deleted azure webapp through azure portal. It seems it is deleted because when I run: 
`az webapp list`

my deleted web app is not showing. But I can still access it *oldwebapp.azurewebsites.net*. 
And it's showing in google search as well. Is there any cache I need to clear or other places I can check to fully remove it? 
Also checked other places if there is any connection to this old web app, but didn't find any or don't know where to look.

Comment: What does it show when you access the URL?

Comment: Open an InPrivate window and try to access your web app again to make sure if it is the cache's issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also encountered a similar situation and found that the resource has been deleted after checking in portal. Sometimes visit it using InPrivate window also succeed.

It seems that this is a **bug**, and you don't need to care about it, or if necessary, you can also submit a bug in a GitHub Issue.

If you need to use the url again by creating a new webapp with the same name, try deploy a new project and access it, it should be refresh to the new one.

Comment: Ok it's not showing in InPrivate. Strange because I cleared all caches. Thanks for pointing it out. Tried to reach azure technical service, but don't have support plan yet :D